# Checking that a process has died

Tags: linux

I am making a client server application wherein when the client process is terminated using red(x)button i need to show a message on server side that the client is disconnected. I am using the pid of the client as a factor for checking. How to detect on the server side for a killed process?
Namedpipes have been used as an IPC.

Comment: Does red(x)button supports some close event? If yes then you can register to server when client is launched and de-register when closed. Pid can be exchanged during these messages using your IPC.

Comment: Yes, red button will support sudden disconnection/closing of the client.

Comment: I meant, does the button supports programmable event (So that your code executes before client dies). If yes, you can try the first comment. 
Which programming language, are you using?

Comment: C programming language. No the button doesn't support programmable event.

Comment: I guess, you are running your client from bash shell and then closing the shell. Since your program is child of shell, killing the shell [red(x)button] will generate a signal (SIGHUP). You can register a signal handler for SIGHUP and then send your pid to Server (Basically DeRegister message). This can be printed on Server console. If using any other lib, please mention it. 
For more details:- man 2 signal, man 7 signal

Comment: I am already using SIGHUP in my code, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't think there is any error or logical issue because same signal is able to display sudden server shell closing